# regext lookbehind word having space-characters

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to get table name `course` between `join and on`. there could be any space-character between both.

I've applied the following regex which returns spaces+course. I tried `(?<=join\s+)(\w+)(?=.*on)` but the problem is it says `lookbehind needs to be zero width`

```
(?<=join)\s+(\w+)(?=.*on)

left outer join      course c on s.id = c.id
```

https://regex101.com/r/bT9hG1/1

- I'm trying to find & replace in sublime text editor & adding prefix before table name.

Comment: Just FYI, the error message is incorrect.  I think they meant to say "*fixed* width", but that's not quite true either.  The message goes on to say you can't use quantifiers in lookbehinds; that's the part that's true (in PCRE).

Comment: So much to learn. Great information. will remember that. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `sublime text editor` uses PCRE regex you can use `\K` to reset the matched info:

```
(?<=join\s)\s*\K(\w+)\b(?=.*on)
```

Or in your case, you can use the following expression without using `\b & \s`

```
(?<=join)\s+\K(\w+)(?=.+ on )
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT9hG1/2)

`\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.

Comment: Sweet, didn't knew about that. will accept after 5 mins bcoz SO won't let me before. :)

Comment: Is the \s needed in `join\s` in my current practice i'm not sure if it should be with `join` or not. can you clear please? It works without the \s though. i tried. and what about `\b` before lookbehind condition?

Comment: `\b` is for word boundary. Without `join\s` it will also match `left outer join123      course c on s.id = c.id` which you may not want.

Comment: O_O wow, \s i need you. didn't considered that. can you explain about \b i don't understand the meaning of `word boundary` yet. why is it helpful in my case. as you explained about `join\s`

Comment: Without `\b` it will match `left outer join moon` since there is `on` in `moon` also

Comment: Thank you `PCRE Compatibale Sensei`